# how to upgrade or update the currently installed php version?

Tags: php, update

my current version of PHP installed in my ubuntu 11.04 box , is PHP5.3.5, now how to update it into the latest stable PHP5.3.8  version? 
this [tutorial didn't work for me](http://atik97.wordpress.com/2010/06/12/how-to-upgrade-to-php-5-3-in-ubuntu-9-10/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

9.10 is [EOL on April 2011](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

That means there are no more updates (no bugs or security issues fixed). You should consider upgrading to more recent release. I'd suggest you to upgrade to 10.04 LTS which would be supported till 2015.

Comment: can't we update just the PHP and MySQL only? ,is updating these two softwares has something to do with my current ubuntu version ?

Comment: Short answer: no, you can't, because there's no newer versions of PHP and MySQL build for 9.10. Long answer: maybe you can if you'll biuld them yourself. BUT: there are probably lots of security issues in other packages.

Comment: according to PHP.net 5.3.8 is stable  :(